# prevent bots / scrapers executing javascript to get output

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, bots

I see allot about Cpatcha's and Submission forms / methods to block bots and content **scrapers** / leechers but nothing about blocking those who take the entire JavaScript contents and execute it to obtain and view what it is outputting.

Is it possible to prevent bots executing JavaScript to obtain the output.

I have looked at if statements within JavaScipt checking screen resolutions, keyboards, mouse, touch screens basic human required functions etc but it is a hard area to find information on.

```
if (bot){ //don't execute Javascript don't let the bot get the real output.
return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only known mechanism is to use minification and obfuscation of your javacsript functions. Change them on every deploy or every day through a script process. Another thing is not to have window methods on the global space.

You may want to look at [Web Assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly), but not all browsers have currently adopted it.

There is no straight forward way to achieve this perfectly. If people put enough time they can crack it out.

Comment: Thanks for the information I already use obfuscation but they went a step further by executing the JavaScript instead to obtain the output. So now they are executing obfuscated code what should be a security concern for them.

Comment: once you expose the code or functionality to the client, you lose ownership on what can be done on the frontend.  As a thing which I would not suggest, you could try exposing older function names as functions which don't do anything. But if they are using desktop automation tools or selenium type frameworks to test, you cannot do anything.

Comment: So even doing simple logic checks like IF HTML element ID name exist in JavaScript would not work against them ? I figured maybe their bot would not know what elements and ID's are or should be present on the page. Even present Javascript var's from other scripts.

Comment: Bots come in many forms. Some are automated, some learn. it depends on which kind of bot you are trying to fix it for. Some may be selenium recorder scripts for all we know. Its better you move any secure logic which you feel is important to the server side or go with plain HTML without javascript (which may not be a solution for all use cases).

Comment: I once talked to an ecommerce CTO level guy of a decent sized traffic, asked how you'd optimize or identify bots for price scraping. He said we dont. Its hardly 0.1% of the traffic and its not really important a problem till someone actually impacts the business or slows the websites.

Comment: The JavaScript they will execute contains nothing of a security nature it is obfuscated to hide video stream links to prevent bandwidth abuse / waste. Kodi python scripts was the main culprit a long time ago. Now they execute JavaScript it is a cat and mouse game.

Comment: to avoid bandwidth abuse, you should try recognising at the server and returning appropriate status or considering sending signed requests. for example: if you are calling api.example.com from www.example.com. have www.example.com embed urls for api.example.com/?sign=abcdef. This can be generated and verified at api.example.com . See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html on how s3/aws does it.

Comment: Already do use a salted hash key making URL's unique. I am currently investing your previous advise on selenium and came across the following security resource for blocking PhantomJavascript https://blog.shapesecurity.com/2015/01/22/detecting-phantomjs-based-visitors/

Comment: Not just one url being unique .for each request your webserver generates, you should have mechanism to identify and stop the request if it was too old. that way you have a proper handshake between your webserver and content server serving the users.

Comment: if someone wants to bypass, they can. FYI. they just need to modify the method names after cloning the phantomjs scripts.